# Action Cable with passenger and nginx on production server without ssl

Tags: nginx, redis, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger, actioncable

**I am using action cable with rails for api.**

Action Cable working fine on development server.But when we upload all action cable process on production server it's not working properly.

**I'm using below configuration in my production.rb file:**

```
  config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  config.action_cable.url = ENV['ACTION_CABLE_URL_PRO'] 
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ENV['ACTION_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_PRO'],/http:\/\/example.*/]
  conf
  config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```

**routes.rb file**

```
mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

**Cable.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/0
  channel_prefix: App_development

test:
  adapter: async
  url: redis://localhost:6379/0
  channel_prefix: App_development

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
  channel_prefix: App_production
```

It's gives me the error on rails production server with multiple users only:

**Ignoring message processed after the WebSocket was closed** and also on app side it's gives me the error **onFailedcom.hosopy.actioncable.ActionCableException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout**